# mysql group by multiple columns with count - not grouping all answers

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I am grouping by two columns and trying to figure out why two exact sets of columns are not adding together. I have removed all other data and am trying to get a single set to work properly, that in theory will get the other sets to work as well. Here is the example output I am getting:

```
Question | Answer      | Count
Waiver   | Waiver Info |  11
Waiver   | Waiver Info |   7
```

Expected output:

```
Question | Answer      | Count
Waiver   | Waiver Info |  18
```

The Query is:

```
SELECT question, answer, count(*) as `count` FROM orderitems oi
JOIN orders o ON o.orderid = oi.oid 
JOIN ordermeta om ON om.groupid = oi.groupid
WHERE question = 'waiver:'
group by question, answer
order by question, answer
```

There will be other questions and answers that are separated into more info with counts, so I must have both group by columns and both order by columns... The question and answer are the exact same, so I can't figure out why they are not adding the two rows together.

Answer (score 0):

You may have spaces in fields,that's why it is showing you two rows instead of single result. You can replace spaces with blank string before grouping.

Here is the way to do that:

```
SELECT question, answer, count(*) as `count` FROM orderitems oi
JOIN orders o ON o.orderid = oi.oid 
JOIN ordermeta om ON om.groupid = oi.groupid
WHERE question = 'waiver:'
group by replace(question,' ',''), replace(answer,' ','')
order by question, answer
```